# Client WebPart (apppart), I need to explain some settings

Tags: client-object-model, settings, markup, app-part

Property element

```
<Property xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
Name="Text"
DefaultValue="Text"
Multilingual= "true" | "false"
PersonalizationScope="user" | "shared"
PersonalizableIsSensitive= "true" | "false"
Type= "string" | "int" | "boolean" | "enum"
RequiresDesignerPermission= "true" | "false"
WebBrowsable= "true" | "false"
WebCategory="Text"
WebDescription="Text"
WebDisplayName="Text"
ManagedLinkConvertServerLinksToRelative= "true" | "false"
ManagedLinkFixup= "true" | "false" >
  <EnumItems>
    <EnumItem 
    Value="Text"
    WebDisplayName="Text" />
  </EnumItems>
</Property>`
```

What is the purpose of these attributes?

```
ManagedLinkConvertServerLinksToRelative
ManagedLinkFixup
```

Comment: have you find answer for this ?

Comment: Not yet, so I do not know.